# remove sharp edged circles on product images

Tags: image

Here you can see category image occupied more space although it is a small image.

i want to decrease the image occupying space.

another thing is on same link, you can see 2 sharp edged circles on product images .

I want to remove 2 sharp edged circles. 2 sharp edged circles will display only if we use "product labels".

[here "Ideal for laptop" is product label.]

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upload a product image Magento won't just use the image exactly as it's uploaded, it will resize it according to the image type you have selected.  What you are seeing here is just the resized version of the small image you initially uploaded.

You can't by default add a product 'label' on top of a normal product image, you will need an extension for that (you can find a few different options for this on connect marketplace).

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for reply. I uploaded in .png format. yes, i used em_product label extension. so "Ideal for laptop" label is displaying. but those 2 sharp edged circles images are also displaying, please help me to remove 2 sharp edged circles. thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, well if its an issue with a third party extension you are going to need to contact the extension developer with your query.